# qt - how to open external app without crash

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I've written my app using allegro library and I want to open this app from qt. Problem is that allego app for work needs to open external font file.  When I'm using:

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
myProcess->start("C:/allegroApp.exe");
```

app crash occurs. Does somebody knows how to open it without a crash?

Comment: For crashes, you need to include the stack trace and the exact error messages in the question -- otherwise there's no way for anyone to know what the issue really is.

Comment: Yes,  but i know why crash occur but don't know how to fix it . Problem seems to be with that when i open this allegro app from qt it can't load other external font file. When i open  allegro app manually from windows it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  Please provide the stack trace and exact error message, as already requested by others.  If you want someone to help you, then you have to help them by giving all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to set `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory` correctly. Set the working dir to the one usually used when starting that app.